# Karate - Unable to replace graphql query variables through data driven scenario outline 'examples'

Tags: automation, graphql, karate

I was trying graphql query which has variables for a query e.g.

```
{
"extquery": {
"where": {
"and": [
{"firstName": "<fname>", "wildcard":false},
{"lastName":"<lname>" , "wildcard":false},
{"birthDate": "2099-02-07"},


]
},
"limit": {
"size": 10
}
}
}
```

final query is like :  And request { query: '#(query)', variables: '#(vars)' }

I have tried using below it's not replacing final query  e.g

Examples:
|fname|lname|
|am|tt|

Same is working when we use 'replace' inline used for 'vars' object But i have to try with 'Examples' so i can have data driven tests for different environment.

i am loading both query and variables from separate graphql file

```
        Given def query = read('xyz.graphql')
        Given def variables = read('variables.graphql')
```

I suspect query is object thats why it's not working. it's working well when i have inline text query without variables

Comment: read the docs and examples carefully please. if still stuck, follow this process: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue